# Access to the path denied. Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have Server1 and Server2.

On Server 2 I have a simple PowerShell.ps1  file that creates a text file on shared drive:

```
New-Item -path \\MyShared\Drive\TestFile.txt
```

Executing this file on Server 2 works fine.

Now I want to execute the same file from Server1 using powershell, but it gives me a permission error:

```
# connect to Server2
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1 -Credential myusername
#Execute ps1 file
[Server2]: PS C:\Username\Documents .\PowerShell.ps1
```

**Error message:**

```
New-Item : Access to the path '\\MyShared\Drive\TestFile.txt' is denied.
At C:\Users\Username\Documents\PowerShell.ps1:1 char:1
+ New-Item -path \\\MyShared\Drive\TestFile.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\MyShared\Drive\TestFile.txt:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I tried so many different account, but getting same error over and over.

Execution policy list on Server2:

[image]

Comment: may be try Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned on your server 2 (in a powershell command in mod admin)

Comment: Do you get an error from a manually typed New command?  (New-Item -path \\MyShared\Drive\TestFile.txt)

Comment: No, in powershell on server2 this command works perfectly.

Comment: It’s a double hop issue

Answer (score 0):

As @Doug Maurer mentioned it is a double hop issue.
PowerShell isn't passing the credential I authenticated with to the remote resource.

So in order to solve it, first I need to `register a session configuration` using `myaccount` on `Server02` by running this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server02 -ScriptBlock { Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Ipswitch -RunAsCredential 'domain\account' -Force }
```

Then, instead of using credential, I will be using `-ConfigurationName Ipswitch`

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server2 -ScriptBlock { C:\Users\Username\Documents\PowerShell.ps1 } -ConfigurationName Ipswitch
```

That's it.

Source: https://blog.ipswitch.com/the-infamous-double-hop-problem-in-powershell